# Converting between char and Tchar with perl

Tags: perl, winapi

in order to convert a char string to Tchar on windows there are a macro called Text like below :

TCHAR X[20]=Text("ABCDEDF");

I need to achieve the same thing with perl using win32::api to send my string to function as TCHAR

i.e

my $string="ABCDEDF";
how to convert it to TCHAR and send it to some function using win32::api module.

Comment: What has it got to do with C++?

Answer (score 0):

```
use Encode qw(encode decode);
my $windowsString = encode("UCS-2LE", "ABCDEDF");
```